# Missing value - Polar plot

Tags: r

Dataset: two bivariate unequal observations:

```
g_d g_a s_d s_a
2   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
2   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
3   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
3   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
3   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
5   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
6   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
8   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
9   27.75047815 2   27.75047815
10  27.75047815 2   27.75047815
3   17.19518769 2   27.75047815
3   13.21767851 2   27.75047815
4   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
4   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
5   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
6   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
6   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
6   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
7   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
8   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
9   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
9   13.21767851 3   27.75047815
11  13.21767851 3   27.75047815
11  13.21767851     
14  13.21767851     
14  13.21767851     
14  13.21767851     
15  13.21767851     
16  13.21767851     
17  13.21767851     
24  13.21767851     
2   30.90877312     
2   30.90877312     
2   30.90877312     
2   30.90877312     
2   30.90877312     
3   30.90877312     
3   30.90877312     
3   30.90877312
```

I am trying to make 2 polar plots side by side in same plot window using following commands

Codes:

```
d = read.table("D:/POLAR_1.txt", sep="\t", header=T)
attach(d)
summary(d)
library(plotrix)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

For first polar plot:

```
polar.plot(NA, NA, clockwise=TRUE, rp.type="", start=90,radial.lim=c(0, 35), 
radial.cex=0.3, box.radial=TRUE, show.grid.labels=1, boxed.radial=FALSE)

polar.plot(g_d, g_a, clockwise=TRUE, rp.type="s", start=90, point.symbols=19, 
show.grid.labels=3, par(cex=0.8), add=TRUE)
```

For 2nd polar plot:

```
polar.plot(NA, NA, clockwise=TRUE, rp.type="", start=90,radial.lim=c(0, 35), 
radial.cex=0.3, box.radial=TRUE, show.grid.labels=1, boxed.radial=FALSE, add=TRUE)

polar.plot(s_d, s_a, clockwise=TRUE, rp.type="s", start=90, point.symbols=19, 
show.grid.labels=3, par(cex=0.8), add=TRUE)
```

Result: I can get the 1st plot but for second plot I am getting following message:

## Error report:

```
Error in if (grid.pos[1] < radial.lim[1]) grid.pos <- grid.pos[-1] : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

## Question?

As the 2nd dataset have some missing values (because of less observation), so I am getting this error. So, wondering how to deal with this error.

Comment: A reproducible example would help people offer suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry I didn't add the library: library(plotrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for example:

[image]

```
library(plotrix)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
polar.plot(NA, NA, clockwise=TRUE, rp.type="", start=90,radial.lim=c(0, 35), 
           radial.cex=0.3, box.radial=TRUE, show.grid.labels=1, boxed.radial=FALSE)
polar.plot(g_d, g_a, clockwise=TRUE, rp.type="s", start=90, point.symbols=19, 
           show.grid.labels=3, par(cex=0.8), add=TRUE)

## here remove add=TRUE      
polar.plot(NA, NA, clockwise=TRUE, rp.type="", start=90,radial.lim=c(0, 35), 
             radial.cex=0.3, box.radial=TRUE, show.grid.labels=1, boxed.radial=FALSE)
## use na.omit to remove missing values
polar.plot(na.omit(s_d), na.omit(s_a), clockwise=TRUE, rp.type="s", start=90, point.symbols=19, 
           show.grid.labels=3, par(cex=0.8), add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - @agstudy. Is there any way to place radial axis (0 to 35) to be placed outside the plot? and Put "Degree" symbol in circular axis value as superscript?